# Data access layer design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, data-access-layer, dataobjects.net

I need to build a data access layer and I am looking for the right design pattern.

what I need is:

1. object mapping: it shouldn't be too complicated and not generic.
2. I have a lot of look up tables and I need to a good way to load them. I don't care about starting time (when the program starts up), what I care is to minimizing the number of connections to the db and on the other hand not killing the virtual memory.
3. relationships: I have a lot of connected objects which relate to each other and I need a generic way to load as much as relationships as I want.

Number 2(above) is most critical for me. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend trying to rewrite this - it's hard to work out what you're trying to say. Foxes? Chunky bacon? I'm confused.

Comment: probably means "**focus** on number 2 as its the most critical"

Comment: shuky, are you interested in writing everything on your own, or would a framework that does most of what you want (like Hibernate) be acceptable?

Comment: I also agree that more precise description is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Facade pattern could be used here.

and maybe the Singleton pattern too.